# Crystal Report, VB.net : "Unable to Access Database, database error 207"

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I have created a  crystal report with 3 sub reports s1,s2,s3. It works fine with preview. I have connected the report to database through Command.
But when I Try to run through Vb.net code, I get this error -> Unable to access database.
I have connected all the sub reports same way and same 4 parameters.
when i remove connection to s2 sub report, vb.net code works.
when i reconnect s2 sub report vb.net code gives error.
I have deleted s2 sub report and recreated it. Same Problem.
In all scenarios report preview works and shows real time data correctly.

I really do not know what am i missing. please help.
Is the info provided enough? has anyone gone through the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Out of 4 parameters, p1 was declared in Command while connecting database, other 3 were declared in crystal report. I had linked sub reports with all 4 parameters which was not necessary.
when i removed the parameter p1 from linking sub reports window, the report worked.